# Python Flask - Pyodbc User as the actual user and not IIS Super User

Tags: python, sql-server, iis, applicationpoolidentity

We have a **Python Flask** app hosted on **IIS 8** with **Windows Authentication** is turned on.

The **ApplicationPool** for this IIS app has **Identity** set to a **Custom Account**. Let's say for example,

```
super_usr
```

This account has **SQL Authorization** for the **SQL Server** Databases it is going to access.

Let's say a certain **Local User** is trying to access the Flask application.

```
local_usr
```

The Flask app is able to get the local user's name using

```
request.environ['REMOTE_USER']
```

The way PyODBC is used to connect to the database is it uses

```
TrustedConnection=yes
```

as a part of the SQL Connection String.

```
DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=XYZ;PORT=123;Trusted_Connection=yes;
```

So PyODBC opens the connection under the context of the **super_usr** and ***NOT*** the **local_usr** as IIS has **super_usr** running the Server.

Now we are looking for a way so that PyODBC opens connection as the **local_usr**. We don't want to ask the **local_usr** for their **password** and keep the **Windows Authentication** on.

This is for the purpose of having SQL Authorization for the Windows Authenticated User [**local_usr**] and not the Account running on IIS Application Pool [**super_usr**].

Is there a way in IIS when the SQL Server are not on the Same Box to authorize the authenticated user instead of passing a certain account to the Application Pool Identity?

Has anyone faced this problem before? And if yes, what's the ideal way to get around this?

Thanks in Advance.